# How to resolve ggplot2 error: data must be a dataframe or an object coercible by `fortify()`

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)
Project1Data <- read.csv("D:/Project1Data.csv")
Project1Data = ordered(Project1Data$Breakfast, levels = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
ggplot(Project1Data, aes(x=Breakfast)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=Employment))
```

Show in New Window

```
Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a <data.frame>, or an object coercible by
  `fortify()`, or a valid <data.frame>-like object coercible by
  `as.data.frame()`.
Caused by error in `.prevalidate_data_frame_like_object()`:
! `dim(data)` must return an <integer> of length 2.
Backtrace:
  1. ggplot2::ggplot(Project1Data, aes(x = Breakfast))
  2. ggplot2:::ggplot.default(Project1Data, aes(x = Breakfast))
  4. ggplot2:::fortify.default(data, ...)
 11. ggplot2:::validate_as_data_frame(model)
 12. ggplot2:::.prevalidate_data_frame_like_object(data)
```

Can someone explain to me what is this type of error in R, I have the same code with my friend but I can't run the code, meanwhile he can.

Comment: G'Day, it looks like the Project1Data.csv does not come through as a data frame when it is read. What comes back when you use ```str()``` on Project1Data? Is it a data frame?

Answer (score 2):

The `data=` argument needs to be a `data.frame`. It starts as one, but when you overwrite `Project1Data` with the results of `ordered(.)`, it becomes a simple vector, the data in the `Breakfast` column as a factor. What you need to do is save the return value back into the column itself.

I think you need to do either the dplyr method

```r
Project1Data <- Project1Data |>
  mutate(Breakfast = ordered(Breakfast, levels = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

or you can choose the base R method

```r
Project1Data$Breakfast <- ordered(Project1Data$Breakfast, levels = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

This of course needs to be done on the whole frame, you cannot recover the whole frame after you've overwritten it. You need to `read.csv(.)` again.

Fully, perhaps

```r
Project1Data <- read.csv("D:/Project1Data.csv")
Project1Data <- Project1Data |>
  mutate(Breakfast = ordered(Breakfast, levels = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)))
ggplot(Project1Data, aes(x=Breakfast)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=Employment))
```